# GWT: How to invert a Vertical Panel of buttons

Tags: gwt, user-interface

I have a vertical panel that contains a set of buttons. When clicking on the base button, the panel expands and shows the set of buttons that are part of the vertical panel. Since this base button is towards the bottom of hte UI, I have made changes to the CSS in order to make the expanded buttons appear flowing upwards as opposed to downwards. Nevertheless, it seems as if the page expands downwards in the expanded state, and this leads to an addition of a scroll on the page, which is completely undesirable.

Is there a way to add buttons to a vertical panel that builds up (is inverted) as opposed to building down? I would really prefer not to have to add the buttons in a different order and then play with the CSS again if at all possible. Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VerticalPanel is the wrong widget for your layout. You should use a PopupPanel and a very simple CSS. When a user presses a button, you show this PopupPanel by calling .showRelativeTo() method. It will do all the calculations for you, and it will show it downward or upward depending on the browser window size and position of your button.

Within the PopupPanel you add a FlowPanel, and you add your buttons to this FlowPanel. Apply this style to the FlowPanel:

```
.menu {
    width: 100px;
}
.menu input {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am wondering if there is a way to force the Popup panel to always open upwards?

Comment: Yes. Instead of using showRelativeTo() you can simply set the coordinates yourself. Use .setPopupPositionAndShow() method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to `just invert the direction` as from my understanding you want the button panel to float on top of the existing page. Webpages follows a flow structure and do not get stacked up unless you specify.

You may have to change your entire layout into an absolute panel, or use CSS (as you said you do not want to but this is definitely easier than the former one) so you can place the panel anywhere you want.

CSS:

```
.button-panel{
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 319px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Java:

```
YourVerticalPanel.addStyleName("button-panel");
```